# Exporting analytics data in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

We are trying to extract analytics data from Sitecore 8.1. We have used Engagement Intelligence Datamart tool in past for earlier version but this is not compatible with latest version. Can you please suggest some way to export analytics data to be used with another reporting tool like Power BI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this tool. https://github.com/Sitecore/experience-extractor.

This is a community tool for exporting experience data from Sitecore to Analyze, present and share Sitecore data with external tools such as Excel, Power BI, R and Tableau.

Experience Extractor runs data processing tasks (ETL) on Sitecore’s domain model, and export data from the xDB as tabular data.